# BeautifullSoup returns the whole DIV, but without the value

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This might be a bit of a basic question, but either I do not know how to phrase it, or I'm not finding the answer.

So, I want to scrape a specific value of a website (**18.73kWh**) in this scenario.

```
> <div class="itemized-bill-header-consumption"data-bind="text:$root.formatItemizedbillConsumption(key.consumption,key.type)">18.73kWh</div>
```

So I am using Python and BeutifullSoup to get the value,

```
kwh = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"itemized-bill-header-consumption"})
```

The thing is, that as a result, i'm getting

```
[<div class="itemized-bill-header-consumption" data-bind="text:$root.formatItemizedbillConsumption(key.consumption,key.type)"></div>]
```

Which is pretty much everything minus the value I want... and I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance for  your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `select`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc="""<div class="itemized-bill-header-consumption"data-bind="text:$root.formatItemizedbillConsumption(key.consumption,key.type)">18.73kWh</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

kwh = soup.select("div", class_="itemized-bill-header-consumption")[0].text
print(kwh)
```

Output will be:

```
18.73kWh
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get_text()` method.

```py
html = """
<div class="itemized-bill-header-consumption"data-bind="text:$root.formatItemizedbillConsumption(key.consumption,key.type)">18.73kWh</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
for div in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"itemized-bill-header-consumption"}):
    print(div.get_text())
```

Output

```
18.73kWh
```